# Free web service for consumer drug information

Tags: web-apps

I want to know if there are web services that provide consumer drug information like side effects, the drugs composition(ingredients), manufacturer, warnings related to the drug....so on.If you know one, Please tell me as I need it desperately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you use the tag [tag:web-development]?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a data source available on the web, rather than for software to exploit a data source. See [Can I ask for recommended websites?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites)

Answer (score 2):

The reference in French is [Vidal](http://www.vidal.fr/):

- free
- side effects
- composition (ingredients)
- warnings related to the drug
- many other info:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the references in English is the [Martindale](https://www.medicinescomplete.com/mc/martindale/current/login.htm):

- side effects
- composition (ingredients)
- warnings related to the drug
- many other info:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The other reference in English is the [Physicians' Desk Reference (PDR)](http://www.pdr.net/):

- free
- side effects
- composition (ingredients)
- warnings related to the drug
- many other info:

E.g. [Amoxapine](http://www.pdr.net/drug-summary/amoxapine?druglabelid=2079&id=2163)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.However,I was looking for web services not web sites.I need a web service so that I can fetch data from a server through a web serivce and display in on the app I'm working on.If you know any web services, pls tell me.

Comment: @avidProgrammer OK will do (but can't think of any ATM).